# Double integration (Jacobian)

Tags: integration

If $R:x^2+y^2=a^2$ is the region, evaluate 
$$\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
I can't understand how to use the Jacobian method in this problem. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the region? After that just apply Fubini...

Comment: @Riquelme The region will be a circle of radius a....but what to do next?

Comment: transform it to polar coordinates. The exponential will become $e^{-r^2}$. How does $dx\ dy$ transform?

Comment: @Andrei I also can't understand how to transform dxdy into dr dtheta

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the change of variables $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. The Jacobian is
$$
J = \begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & r\cos\theta 
\end{vmatrix} = r\cos^2\theta + r\sin^2\theta = r.
$$
I will assume that you meant $x^2+y^2\leqslant a^2$ since the set $\{x^2+y^2=a^2\}$ has measure zero and hence the integral of any function over that set is zero. We have
$$
R = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2\leqslant a^2\} = \{(r,\theta)\in[0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi]: 0\leqslant r\leqslant a\},
$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy &= \iint_R re^{-r^2}\ \mathsf dr\ \mathsf d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a re^{-r^2}\ \mathsf dr\ \mathsf d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\frac12(1-e^{-a^2})\ \mathsf d\theta\\
&= \pi(1-e^{-a^2}).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much